# Meaning of a fictional place-name: 星嶺鷹守学園

Tags: meaning, readings, proper-nouns

This phrase has helpful but rather confusing furigana (星嶺鷹守学園{セイレイタカガミガクエン}).

I'm reading it to mean "star-ridge takagami campus", with star ridge being the name of the specific campus and takagami being the place/town.

In more correct(?) English, "Star-ridge campus of/in Takagami".

Taking 鷹守{タカガミ} literally would be "falcon director(of the provincial governors under the ritsuryo system)" which makes no sense.

How do Japanese people read/tell fictional place created by entertainment media?

Comment: My guess is that "鷹守" is just a name and doesn't have any deep meaning, though the Kanji it is made from sound (subjectively) "cool" to me (i.e. "hawk" + "protect")

Comment: @Locksleyu What do  you think about the first part? Would normally be pronounced "hoshimine" but here is pronounced "seirei".

I have seen some references to things ending in "rei" meaning something like "northern mountain(s)" or in this case "star mountain(s)"

Unlike the  鷹守 part this makes sense when translated.

Comment: Without knowing the story I can't say for sure, but my guess is it is some reference to some other word that is pronounced 'seirei', such as 精霊 (spirit)

Comment: @Locksleyu The story does has themes of magic and angels. Reading it as "Holy ghost(spirit) campus of Takagami" sounds too literal. I'm sure this is intended to be a pun, I'm sure a lot of fictional names in Japanese media are.

Comment: Well, I happen to know a [Christian school named せいれい学園](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1%E6%B3%95%E4%BA%BA%E8%81%96%E9%9A%B7%E5%AD%A6%E5%9C%92), and many Christian schools have 聖【せい】 (="Saint") in their names, so I personally do feel a bit of such nuance in this fictional name. But I don't know if it's incidental or intentional.

Answer (score 5):

Simply, 星嶺鷹守学園 is one long proper noun. So you should translate it as "Seirei Takagami Academy/School/etc" without thinking of the etymology. You don't want New York to be translated as 新ヨーク even if "new" definitely means 新 :-)

And it's very difficult to analyze this phrase "etymologically", too. Of course it's easy to split it into kanji and explain the meaning of each kanji ("star-ridge-hawk-protector"), but basically, both 星嶺 and 鷹守 come off to me as simple "names" to me. 鷹守 might mean something else somewhere in the history, but I'm not familiar with such a job anyway.

Note:

- Alternatively, you may translate it even as "Seirei Takagami Gakuen Academy" or something like that. It's like "Rio Grande river", "Mont Blanc mountains", though.
- "X Campus" is simply "Xキャンパス" in Japanese (eg "○○学園(の)△△キャンパス").